# Is it possible in CSS: height: height+50px?

Tags: html, css, less

I need to increase the `height` (that is not defined *a priori*) of a div `+50px` on `:hover`.

```css
.foo{
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.foo:hover{
  height: height+50px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">foo text</div>
```

- Is it possible with `css` only?
- Is it possible using `less`?

**PS.**

Practical (more complex) need: I have a "sprite" image

```
1234
HHHH
5678
HHHH
```

where H is the hover image for the respective initial image.
[image]
I can calculate the X and Y coordinate for each class (1,2,3) but for `:hover` I would like just to go down with imageheight:

```
:hover {background-position-y: background-position-y - @imgheight}
```

Comment: it's not possible with pure css, but you can do it with less or with javascript

Comment: how can I do it with less?

Comment: @Serge Actually i may have solution, but would like to know, Why do you wanna achieve this. Is it to fit more content or just the look or effect purpose.

Comment: @divy3993: I updated the OP with practical details...

Comment: Note that it would be easier and more resource friendly to only use the icons without the shadow and then one hover add `box-shadow` to the containing element. (But won't work in older browsers that don't support box-shadow)

Comment: @BramVanroy: `box-shadow` will it work on the `background-image`?

Comment: No, but it will work on the containing element. If you want I'll make a fiddle.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qmdf795b/

Comment: @BramVanroy: this one could solve my problem... http://jsfiddle.net/qmdf795b/3/ Thanks!

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, so you can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment: I advise another approach. Simply set the box-shadow to the container element, like so:

```css
a {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('http://nationalevents.cityofhope.org/images/content/pagebuilder/facebook-icon.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: block;
  /*border: 1px solid white;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Some text</a>
```

Note that the box-sizing and border-radius are set on a, and not on hover. This is done to prevent any additional processing time on hover. It's best to keep the changes on hover minimal.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could consider using pseudo-elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/pjr7wbhk/2/

```
.foo{
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.foo:hover{
  color: white;
}

.foo:hover::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I need to **increase** the height, not setting it to 50px... try setting `.foo{    height: 100px;}`

Comment: As you see, I don't touch the height of your precious `.foo` directly. I'm setting the height of the `::after` pseudoelement. Read, would you kindly.

Comment: @Serge This _does_ increase the height, it's basically adding another element under the text with a height of `50px` so it's effectively **text height** + **pseudo element height**.

Comment: I understand, but I need to **increase** the height, not to set it to 50px... if the height in a moment is 100px, it should became 150px... if is 50% it should become 50%+50px. see the fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/pjr7wbhk/3/

Comment: @Serge The difference in your fiddle is that you are setting a `height` on `.foo` which would break this particular method. You have suggested in your question and comments that the `height` is not specified so would this be a problem?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes: I agree here http://jsfiddle.net/pjr7wbhk/4/ will effectively add 50px... now I think that will not work on the `background-position-y` property with pseudo elements, like described in the practical sample

Answer (score 0):

If you have your height variable like this:

```css
@foo-height : 50px; /* here goes your initial height value */
```

you can write these rules in your .less file:

```css
.foo {
    background: red;
    width: 50%;
    height: @foo-height;
    text-align: center;
}
.foo:hover {
    height: ~'calc(@{foo-height} + 50px)';
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: no, it's not possible that way. You can do it like I show you here with predefined height. Otherwise you gonna use javascript

Answer (score 0):

Using an extra html element and some abs/rel positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/pjr7wbhk/6/

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="inner-helper">foo text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo {
    position: relative;
}
.foo .inner-helper {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
}
.foo:hover .inner-helper {
    bottom: -50px;
}
```